# jQuery scroll down the page to certain no of pixels

Tags: jquery, scroll

With jQuery how can I make it so an element is clicked and the browser scrolls down the page to certain number of pixels?

This isn't relative to the current scroll position. Clicking the element needs to always make the page be scrolled down to the same number of pixels.

I want this to be immediate, no animation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 
    http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/
    http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work and doesn't require a plug in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.first-cont').click(function() {
        setTimeout(function() { 
        window.scrollTo(0, 1) }, 
        100);
    }); 
});
```